# stringr str_replace on multiple patterns and replacements?

Tags: r, stringr

I tried

```
> str_replace("abcdef", c("b", "d"), c(b="B", d="D"))
[1] "aBcdef" "abcDef"
```

hoping for

```
[1] "aBcDef"
```

How can we replace each pattern with a specific replacement with one function call to `stringr::str_replace`?

Comment: You could do with a `chartr` solution as indicated in the answers here (such solution is mentioned at the beginning of the question I linked). On the other hand, packages are open source and the code is accessible on GitHub - so you can check the source code and perhaps even copy/paste it without the need for installing a package.

Answer (score 24):

The `chartr()` solution was new to me too, but I wanted to replace single characters with multiple. Eventually found a `stringr` (v1.4.0) solution that's quite simple. In fact it's in the help page, once it dawned that this calls for `str_replace_all`.

```
# one approach that both: answers the original question with stringr
str_replace_all("abcdef", c(b="B", d="D"))
[1] "aBcDef"

# and answers a more general question
str_replace_all("abcdef", c(b="BB", d="DDD"))
[1] "aBBcDDDef"
```

Comment: to make this a little clearer, the character vector structure is c("pattern you want to find" = "replacement value"). the `stringr::str_replace_all` function allows you to pass multiple patterns to apply to a single string using this approach: `str_replace_all("Hello World", c("World" = "my Darling", "H\\w+" = "Goodbye"))`

Answer (score 15):

With `str_replace` an option is to wrap with `reduce2`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
reduce2(c('b', 'd'), c('B', 'D'),  .init = 'abcdef', str_replace)
#[1] "aBcDef"
```

---

Or with anonymous function call

```
reduce2(c('b', 'd'), c('B', 'D'),  .init = 'abcdef',
         ~ str_replace(..1, ..2, ..3))
#[1] "aBcDef"
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. Do you know if there's a way using *only* `stringr` and base R functions?

Comment: @stevec that would be a `for` loop `for(i in seq_along(v1)) v1 <- str_replace(v1, pat[i], repl[i])`

Comment: @stevec The `str_replace` function behavior is different than you expect i.e for multple pattern, replacement, it does the pairwise corresponding replacement instead of updating the original string.  `reduce2` doesn't have `Reduce2` replacement in `base R`.  Only way is `for` loop (other options I am not aware of)

Comment: @akrun I want you to know that for years I've been finding your answers all over SO, and they always seem to be correct, helpful, and clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This matches each character and if it equals `b` it replaces it with `B`, if it equals `d` it replaces it with `D` and otherwise it leaves it as is.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn(".", list(b="B", d="D"), "abcdef")
## [1] "aBcDef"
```

These also work:

```
gsubfn("[bd]", list(b="B", d="D"), "abcdef")
## [1] "aBcDef"

gsubfn("[bd]", toupper, "abcdef")
## [1] "aBcDef"

# only needs base R
chartr("bd", "BD", "abcdef")
## [1] "aBcDef"
```

Comment: `chartr("bd", "BD", "abcdef")` is very interesting, I had not seen this before.

Comment: agree - thanks for introducing me to `chartr()`

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in a pipe

```
str_replace('abcdef', 'b', 'B') %>% str_replace(., 'd', 'D')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to refactor into one function call