# Is there any way to detect a specific word and replace a whole string with another in R language?

Tags: r

I want to replace char value in R with another, it should be like [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNsd0.png)

The key word to work is "Texas". And there is any way that I can do it with multiple files at once.

I have tried like this:   `df[df=="121 Texas"]<-"Texas"`   but it's clearly not smart at all when it comes to work with many dataframe at the same time.

Comment: Please don't post links to images! Try posting e.g. the output from `dput(head(data))` instead.

Comment: Probably `help("gsub")`.

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem cos it's not well explanatory enough but you can try and check the glue package

Comment: maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129058/stringr-str-replace-on-multiple-patterns-and-replacements) will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you had a dataframe with a column named "Original" and you wanted to replae all the entries in that column that contained the letters "Texas" as a substring with just the character value "Texas":

```
  df$Original[ grepl("Texas", df$Original) ] <- "Texas"
```

The `grepl` is one of the regex functions. It returns a logical value. The "[" function on the LHS of "<-" (technically the "[<-" function) can accept a logical index and only do the replacements for those items that register TRUE in the `grepl` test.