# Is there a better way to replace multiple patterns inside of a string?

Tags: r

Whenever I need to do text replacement, it's rare that I only have to replace one pattern.  I often find myself stringing together multiple `str_replace_all()` calls, one after another.  The example code below feels very repetitive.  Is there a way to do this with only one call to `str_replace_all()`?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

text <- r'(mother, father, grandmother, and grandfather)'

# is there a better way to do this?
text %>% 
  str_replace_all(
    pattern = r'(\bmother\b)',
    replacement = 'mom'
  ) %>% 
  str_replace_all(
    pattern = r'(\bfather\b)',
    replacement = 'dad'
  ) %>% 
  str_replace_all(
    pattern = 'grandmother',
    replacement = 'grandma'
  ) %>% 
  str_replace_all(
    pattern = 'grandfather',
    replacement = 'grandpa'
  ) %>% 
  str_replace_all(
    pattern = r'(\band\b)',
    replacement = '&'
  )
#> [1] "mom, dad, grandma, & grandpa"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I'm imagining something with a lookup table.

```
df_lookup <-
  tribble(
    ~pattern,           ~replacement,
    r'(\bmother\b)',    'mom',
    r'(\bfather\b)',    'dad',
    'grandmother',      'grandma',
    'grandfather',      'grandpa',
    r'(\band\b)',       '&'
  )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stringr str\_replace on multiple patterns and replacements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129058/stringr-str-replace-on-multiple-patterns-and-replacements) if not, could you edit your question to include why not? Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform multiple str_replace as follows:

```
str_replace_all(text, 
    c(
        r'(\bmother\b)' = "mom", 
         r'(\bfather\b)' = "dad", 
        'grandmother' = "grandma", 
        'grandfather' = "grandpa",
        r'(\band\b)' = "&")
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `reduce` and `map2` from `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df_lookup <- tribble(
  ~pattern,           ~replacement,
  '\\bmother\\b',     'mom',
  '\\bfather\\b',     'dad',
  'grandmother',      'grandma',
  'grandfather',      'grandpa',
  '\\band\\b',        '&'
)

text_modified <- reduce(
  map2(df_lookup$pattern, df_lookup$replacement, ~list(.x, .y)),
  ~str_replace_all(.x, .y[[1]], .y[[2]]),
  .init = text
)

text_modified
```

```
[1] "(mom, dad, grandma, & grandpa)"
```